# Libgdx animation controller, optimize for culled animations

Tags: animation, 3d, libgdx

I wan't to cull all animations that are not visible to the user. I have tried a crude way where I simply do not call AnimationController.update() if the animated object is not visible. This does not work as I wan't though. Since when a culled object comes back into view it will play the last applied animation (even ones that I applied when they where culled) This is as expected I guess. Animations still needs to be applied to culled object as they might come into view halfway through an animation for example.

I am now looking at subclassing AnimationController, and change the update() method to take into consideration if the object is culled or not. If it is I wan't to only update the "time" and not do any "heavy" operations at all.

My problem is that I am not sure what are the heavy parts an what is the bare minimum I need to update/advance. So I was hoping someone with more insight to the AnimationController class could help me out a bit? Any help welcome, thanks!

```
/** Update any animations currently being played.
 * @param delta The time elapsed since last update, change this to alter the overall speed (can be negative). */
public void update (float delta) {
    if (paused) return;
    if (previous != null && ((transitionCurrentTime += delta) >= transitionTargetTime)) {
        removeAnimation(previous.animation);
        justChangedAnimation = true;
        animationPool.free(previous);
        previous = null;
    }
    if (justChangedAnimation) {
        target.calculateTransforms();
        justChangedAnimation = false;
    }
    if (current == null || current.loopCount == 0 || current.animation == null) return;
    justChangedAnimation = false;
    updating = true;
    final float remain = current.update(delta);
    if (remain != 0f && queued != null) {
        inAction = false;
        animate(queued, queuedTransitionTime);
        queued = null;
        updating = false;
        update(remain);
        return;
    }
    if (previous != null)
        applyAnimations(previous.animation, previous.offset + previous.time, current.animation, current.offset + current.time,
            transitionCurrentTime / transitionTargetTime);
    else
        applyAnimation(current.animation, current.offset + current.time);
    updating = false;
}
```

I was hoping I could do something like only advance transitionCurrentTime, remain and current.time when culled...?

Comment: I did not read the whole code and i don't have any experience with those `Animation`s. But usually, it is enough to increase `delta`. So you need a varibale, which sotres the elapsed times since last update (lets call it `updTime`). You increase `updTime` by `delta` every frame. If the `Animation` is inside the view, call `update(updTime)` and set `updTime=0f`.

Comment: I looked at that but I can't see how it would work. I.e. an animated character is behind you being culled it does several skills, triggering several animation. After a time, lets say 10 seconds, that character comes into view and has (in reality) 2 seconds left of its current animation. I then send in the accumulated delta of 10 sec to the animation controller, I just can not see that working. Maybe in combination with resetting updTime each time I apply a new animation would work. I'll give that a try, thank you for the comment!

Comment: The `updTime` does always depend on the current `Animation`. If the `Animation` changes, you have to reset it, as the new `Animation` starts from 0.